# Memory effective SetPixel

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I've created a WPF [Audiovisualation](http://s7.directupload.net/images/121125/q469xi5y.png).
To draw the visualation I use a bitmap that sets pixel. You can see the basic idea [here](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/WpfPixelDrawing.html).

The problem is that I have to call `BitmapSource.Create` every second about 30 times. That causes a lot of wasted memory. The `GC` is doing a very nice job but that is not enough.

What can I do to solve that problem? I would need a bitmap that just updates from base byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347331.aspx) as your `BitmapSource`.

Comment: just found it myself but anyway thanks it was was the right solution